# Evaluate an imported function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 js files. 1 is importing the other

```
//Code to import import.js


export default ()=>{
    return
    [
        {
            'key':'dashboard',
            'label': 'Dashboard',
            'type':'top',
            'children': dashboard
        },
        {
            'key':'sal',
            'label': 'Sales',
            'type':'top',
            'children': inventory
        }
    ];
}
```

This is loaded here

```
import menu from './import.js';

export default class Loader {
    getMenu(){
         menu.map((item)=>{
            return `<div>${item.label}</div>`;
         });
     }
}
```

in the render method, menu is a function instead of the array that is being returned. I've also tried running

```
menu().map((item)=>{
            return `<div>${item.label}</div>`;
         });
```

But it still doesn't work

Comment: Well... you're exporting a function, not an array. Not sure what you expect.

Comment: What errors are you facing ? It seems like a bad formed JSON literal.

Comment: In my opinion,your second way is just fine.Is there any more information?

Comment: @deceze yes, that's my question though, how do I evaluate the function that I imported so that I can access the array?

Comment: Your render function need a 'return' key word.

Comment: @gumingfeng running menu() results to undefined instead of the expected array. Also edited the function in the loader class, the return is not the issue since outputting it in the console in the getMenu() method the menu() is undefined

Comment: ^ That information needs to be in the question. "it doesn't work" is not helpful.

Comment: @torazaburo: Which the OP already does in the last example. And the accepted answer is pretty much that anyway. No?

Comment: @torazaburo: Did you look at the question? Same problem. We can change the title to be more generic.

Comment: @torazaburo: Uh? From the dupe answer: *"You're probably stumbling over implicit statement termination, a.k.a. implicit semicolon insertion. The line after return is ignored completely and nothing is returned. This works: [corrected code]"* I updated the title.

Comment: Use a debugger. Examine the value of `menu` after importing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return [//here is the change,write [ with return in same line
    {
        'key':'dashboard',
        'label': 'Dashboard',
        'type':'top',
        'children': dashboard
    },
    {
        'key':'sal',
        'label': 'Sales',
        'type':'top',
        'children': inventory
    }
];
```

Comment: Yup, this got it working. damn that new line.

Comment: A reasonable approach to typos (which is what this is, essentially), is to vote the close the question as a typo, or less preferably, as a dup of some question with the same typo/problem, and/or note the typo in a comment, and/or suggest that the OP run his code through a linter, which would catch this.